# Powershell 2.0 write back to xlsx

Tags: excel, powershell

Cross post from powershell.org..

I am trying to have Powershell read an xlsx for username info, convert to a csv (to be imported) and then write back something to the xlsx so next time it won't reimport the same users.
I don't want to delete the users in the xlsx but am thinking to add a date column or some other data maybe the word "created" and have powershell write this data in an available  column. But then I would have to have my script ignore this new column if contains a old date or the word created?

```
<br> Current xlsx columns headers
<br>      A            B              C 
<br> 1 Full Name, Personal Email,  "write back data"
<br> 2 John Doe   Jdoe@gmail.com,  Created (Sample write back data)
<br> 3 Don Juan   Djuan@gmail.com, Date Imported (sample write back data)
```

Convert to csv code (This part is working fine.)

```
$File = "C:\Scripts\Excel\Accounts.xlsx"
$Savepath1 = "C:\Scripts\Csv\Employee Accounts.csv"
$SheetName1 = "Employee Accounts"
$ObjExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Objexcel.Visible = $false
$Objworkbook=$ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open($File)
$Objworksheet=$Objworkbook.worksheets.item($Sheetname1) 
$Objworksheet.Activate() 
$Objexcel.application.DisplayAlerts= $False
$Objworkbook.SaveAs($SavePath1,6)
$Objworkbook.Close($True)
$ObjExcel.Quit()
```

Here is my current import-csv code

```
$EmployeeAccounts = Import-Csv $savepath1 | Where-Object { $_.Fullname -and $_.PersonalEmail}
```

Things to consider:
There might be additional concatenated info in additional fields added to the xlsx. Therefore excel might count these as used rows if the fields have formulas in them. So I only want to write the data to the new column if there is a username and email address in columns A & B.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to read [this blog post](http://sqlnotesfromtheunderground.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/modifying-excel-documents-with-powershell/) with tons of examples.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I have seen that page. This could work "$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item(1,1).Value2 = "New Value" but How do I specify to do this in the cells that have full name and email only? I also found this....  foreach ( $col in "A", "B") {
  $objexcel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf($objworksheet.Range($col + "1:" + $col + $rows), "<>") - 1
}
I don't know how to put it all together.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it's going to be simpler to import the whole thing, perform your process filtering for entries that don't have anything in the Updated field, update the "Updated" field for each entry that you processed, and then just write the entire thing back to the file. So, something like:

```
$Users = Import-CSV $FilePath
$Users | ?{[String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Updated)} | %{
    Do stuff here
    $_.Updated = Get-Date    
}
$Users | Export-CSV $FilePath -Force -NoTypeInfo
```

**Edit:** Well then, that does complicate things a little bit. So, this one does take a plugin, but it's a plugin that I whole heartedly feel should be included in almost any installation that's functionally used regularly IMHO. The PowerShell Community Extensions (PSCX) can be gotten from [pscx.codeplex.com](http://pscx.codeplex.com/releases) and will grant you access to the command `Out-Clipboard` which is awesome for what you want to do.

```
$Users = Import-CSV $FilePath
$Users | ?{[String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Updated)} | %{
    Do stuff here
    $_.Updated = Get-Date    
}
$Users | Select Updated | ConvertTo-CSV -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation | Out-Clipboard
$SheetName1 = "Employee Accounts"
$ObjExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Objexcel.Visible = $false
$Objworkbook=$ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open($File)
$Objworksheet=$Objworkbook.worksheets.item($Sheetname1) 
$Objworksheet.Activate()
$Range = $Objworksheet.Range("C1","C1")
$Objworksheet.Paste($Range, $false)
$Objexcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Objworkbook.Save()
$Objexcel.DisplayAlerts = $true
$Objworkbook.Close()
$Objexcel.Quit()
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($Objexcel)
```

That will paste your data, header included, into column C.

Comment: I am trying to write back to the original xlsx source file before the conversion to csv. The csv is overwritten each time which is ok. Source_xlsx  >> Convert to Csv>> import to powershell >> write back to source_xlsx. The reason I want to use the xlsx is that it has formatting formulas and tables that will be lost if I just use a csv to begin with. There is a bit more to the xlsx then just those 2 name and email address columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I appreciate the help. I was really trying to stick to stock Powershell commands. How about something like this..  Get the range based on the rows of data in Column A, select the range and if Columns A -ne null and c -eq null enter the word "imported" in column C. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Ug, unfortunately the Com object makes this very cumbersome. It can be done, and fortunately there is a `$Objworksheet.UsedRange` property that helps a bit, but you can't seem to easily select records from arrays returned by the Com object. This will do it though: `$Objworksheet.UsedRange.Rows|%{$_.Cells|?{![string]::IsNullOrEmpty(($_.cells|?{$_.Column -eq 1}|select -expand value2)) -and [string]::IsNullOrEmpty(($_.cells|?{$_.Column -eq 3}|select -expand value2))}|%{$_ | ?{$_.Column -eq 3} | %{$_.Value2 = "Updated"}}}`

Comment: A coworker provided me this and it seemed to work. for ($i = 2; $i -le $rows; $i++) {
  #$i
  #$mws.Cells.Item($i,3).value()
  if ( $mws.Cells.Item($i,1).value() -ne $Null -and $mws.Cells.Item($i,2).value() -ne $Null)
    {
      if ( $mws.Cells.Item($i,3).value() -eq $Null )
        {
            # do your actual processing of creating the accounts here.
            $mws.Cells.Item($i,3) = "$date"
        }
    }
}